# Singleton Logger in Java that can log which class the log method came from and log to multiple areas/machienes

Tags: java, singleton, logging

I would like to do this using java.util.logging if possible, any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give a try at [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/).

> Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J)
>
> The Simple Logging Facade for Java or
>   (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or
>   abstraction for various logging
>   frameworks, e.g. java.util.logging,
>   log4j and logback, allowing the end
>   user to plug in the desired logging
>   framework at deployment time.

Answer (score 2):

It is plain better to NOT use java.util.Logging (JUL) as it is very slow. That being said,
if you must use JUL, you could try using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)/[slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/). SLF4j includes a module that intercepts JUL and uses Logback instead (Logback is probably the fastest/best logger available.) You could also use [xjuli](http://www.x4juli.org/), a log4j to JUL bridge.

If you can use other loggers I recommend using Logback directly over Log4j as Logback is written by the same person who did Log4j, but contains even faster code. (e.g. Logback = Log4j + lessons learned).

Answer (score 0):

[Apache log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/)

Comment: He wants JUL logging. Try http://www.x4juli.org/ for JUL bindings for log4j. I'd rather suggest that you never start a project that uses log4j, as Logback is better in every way than log4j. SLF4j also contains a JUL to SLF4j bridge ( and JCL and log4j to SLF4j) so you can keep the API you have/are comfortable with.